# VBA Excel - If statement for checking table has a filter on it

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, autofilter

I am looking for code that will check to see if the table has a filter on it.  If it has a filter I want to make sure that it's not filtered and show all data, if it doesn't have a filter then I want to put a filter on it.  If the table has a filter and is not filtered then I don't want it to do anything.

Here is what I have so far:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").FilterMode Then
   Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
End If
```

Any help please

Comment: Could you explain *I want to put a filter on it*? Is the table an `Excel` table (list object)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a **table object**, may be this might help

```
Sub myTableFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ol As ListObject
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ol = ws.ListObjects(1)
   
    On Error Resume Next
    If ol.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then ol.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    'ol.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = True
    ol.ShowAutoFilter = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter

Comment: Close, but what happens if there isn't a filter already.  I need that piece added to the code.  What you provided is great if there is already a filter on the table with or without being filtered.

Comment: I just updated the code. If this not it try to show an example.

Comment: Perfect.  This works great.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

### Initialize Filter

- [`Range.AutoFilter method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)
- [`Worksheet.AutoFilterMode property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.autofiltermode)
- [`Worksheet.FilterMode property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.filtermode)

```vb
Sub InitializeFilter()
    With Sheet1 ' or e.g. With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            If .FilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
                MsgBox "Was previously filtered. Now: 'ShowAllData'."
            Else
                MsgBox "'ShowAllData': do nothing."
            End If
        Else
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
            MsgBox "Applying 'AutoFilter' to ""A1""'s 'CurrentRegion' " _
                & "('ShowAllData')."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```